# ZipException for file that can be opened on other programs

Tags: java, zip

I am having following Exception

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:75)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:56)
```

at line

`ZipFile file = new ZipFile(myfile);`

This is happening with particular zip file only, other file works file, But i can open that file in other programs like `winRAR` and `7zip`.
I am using windows xp.

It seems like some corrupt file, but if any one know what is exact cause for this?

Comment: can you try to unzip and zip the file contents back?

Comment: How do you know `myfile` correctly identifies the input?

Comment: i mean, try to open rezipped file in your program

Comment: I am able open re-zipped file at same name and path after replacing

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check:

1. this could be an environment issue, i.e. by using some other external program like winrar to extract a zip, you also change the execution context: process, user, permissions, etc... maybe your Java process cannot access the file for some reason. Try running your Java as admin, just to see if it's related to that.
2. Try a few other zip files, or try to create a zip file from the same java code, and then extract it, the same way you tried extracting the problematic zip (i.e. same java process, same code, same user and permissions, etc). This will allow you to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I have admin rights, and file have full permission also, I have also verified that file is not in use. other zip files works fine. even re-zipped file works fine. Problem is with zip file and i want to identify that